Verify: Trace of Nilpotent matrix is $)$
Can someone verify the proof I have? Let $A$ be a nilpotent matrix. So $A^n=0$ for some $n$. Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $A$ and $v\ne 0$ be an eigenvector associated to $\lambda$. So $$Av=\lambda v\implies 0=A^nv={\lambda}^nv\implies \lambda =0.$$ But trace is sum of eigenvalues. So trace is $0$.
I am assuming the field has characteristic $0$.

The proof seems fine to me. One comment though: “trace is sum of eigenvalues” only works in an algebraically closed field, so you need to pass to the algebraic closure to make this work.
